# Keeping track of what needs to be removed in a linked list

Tags: python, linked-list, stack

I'm using a while loop to loop through a linked list of nodes, with each node having a value that is a stack. If the top value of the stack is the same for 3 nodes in a row, then the top value needs to be removed, and points need to be scored. How would I go about keeping track of which stacks need to have their top value removed? What I have so far (will score the points but I don't know how to keep track of which nodes need to be removed) In addition, I  am NOT allowed to use any sort of python lists at all. In case I wasn't clear, if there are 3 in a row, they are removed and points are scored, similar to bejeweled. Each node has a stack as its value.

```
        cur_node = self._front
        previous = cur_node.get_value().peek() 
        cur_node = cur_node.next
        in_a_row = False
        points_gained = 0
        count = 0 

        while cur_node:
            current = cur_node.get_value().peek()
            if current == previous:
                count = count + 1
            else:
                if in_a_row:
                    points_gained = points_gained + (count ** 2)
                    in_a_row = False
                count = 1

            if count >= 3:
                in_a_row = True
```

Comment: Just curious.  Why can't you use lists?

Comment: It's an assignment for school in which we're not allowed to use lists. I guess it's to teach us linked lists but I feel like a list would be the best way to keep track.

Comment: Wouldn't it make things simpler to use a for loop and hold onto references for the two previous nodes?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by hold onto references please?

Comment: At the end of the for loop: `beforeprevious = previous`, `previous = current`.  Then you can just do something like `if beforeprevious.get_value().peek() == previous.get_value().peek() and previous.get_value().peek() == current.get_value().peek():`

Comment: Ohh. The problem is that the number of items in a row can vary. I think it could possibly be up to five. (It's a game where you drop different colored items into stacks). I was considering a doubly linked list but we're not allowed to use those either. :(

Comment: I don't think it matters how many items are in a row to my algorithm above.  You just walk through the linked list and keep track of the previous two nodes.

Comment: If there are 5 in a row, they all need to be removed, I don't think yours keeps track of all 5.

Comment: Are you allowed to use dictionaries?

Comment: I believe so, but not a list as the value for the dictionary. I think I *may* have figured it out, I'll let you know (if you're interested).

Comment: You could build a dictionary in your loop that contains the top value for each stack.  Then you could iterate through the dictionary.  Voila.  A list implemented in the form of a dictionary.